# Minimum Processor Requirements: 12.04 vs 14.04 vs 16.04

Tags: lubuntu

I've searched around; found the minimum processor requirements for Ubuntu 16.04 in an offical format.
I can't find offical guidelines for 12.04 and 14.04 ... just various people giving their opinions.

Does anyone know the URL(s) for where Ubuntu bury this information?
- I have an old 32-bit machine with a T1350 processor (not even dual-core) running at 1.8GHz
- It's running Windows 10 slowly with it's maximum 4gb of installed RAM.
- I have Lubuntu downloaded ...
- I'm just thinking that Ubuntu may give me a better experience than Lubuntu ... but which to choose ...

Thanks folks.

Regards,
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 desktop requirements:

> Ubuntu Desktop 11.04 and up uses Unity as the default GUI while the previous releases used GNOME Panel by default. In order to run Unity the system needs a more capable graphics adapter.
>
> - 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> - 1024 MiB RAM (system memory)
> - 3D Acceleration capable video card with at least 256 MB onboard memory
> - 5 GB of disk space
>     From experience, we all know that it is recommended to have 2048 MiB RAM to properly run a day-to-day Ubuntu.
>
> A good start should be with minimum 1024 and recommended 2048 MiB RAM.

Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 desktop requirements:

> In order to run Unity the system needs a more capable graphics adapter.
>
> - 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> - 1024 MiB RAM (system memory)
> - Graphics processor and display capable of at least 1024x768
> - 6 GB of disk space
>     From experience, we all know that it is recommended to have 2048 MiB RAM to properly run a day-to-day Ubuntu.
>
> A good start should be with minimum 1024 and recommended 2048 MiB RAM.

Xubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (there is no official system requirements, but this is gathered from many sources)

> - 512 MiB of system memory (RAM)
> - 5 GB of disk space
> - Graphics card and monitor capable of 800x600 resolution
> - 700 MHz Processor

Lubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 (there is no official system requirements, but this is gathered from many sources)

> - Pentium II
> - 128 MiB RAM
> - PAE supported CPU
> - 4GB of disk space

Please comment if you want ones for other flavours.